# Is Tomcat 8.5.23 leaking sockets?

Tags: tomcat, nio

Tomcat 8.5.23 on Amazon linux with HTTP NIO connector.

After some days working, the total number of open files is reached by the tomcat process (256.000). These are a lot of errors traced in catalina.out.

Our application has several queues where, under some conditions, incoming requests are blocked (and also waken up, correctly, under other conditions). Our Tomcat has MaxThreads="500".

What we have seen is:

1. If these queues block more than 500 requests, then Tomcat has no threads available. When this happens, it seems that the number of open files increases, and does not decrease again (so it seems a leak).
2. If we keep the total size of the queues under 500 (now it's 250), everything works fine.

So we are not sure if Tomcat is leaking sockets when incoming requests are coming and finding all tomcat threads busy.

Below some of the traces that are logged into "catalina.out", just if they can help:

1. The first 3 traces appear while Tomcat is working:

   01-Jul-2018 17:07:51.745 GRAVE [http-nio-80-exec-591] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun
    java.lang.NullPointerException
           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.recycle(Http11InputBuffer.java:280)
           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.recycle(Http11Processor.java:1709)
           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.release(AbstractProtocol.java:1050)
           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:1018)
           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

---

```
01-Jul-2018 17:08:58.755 INFORMACIÓN [http-nio-80-exec-767] org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.checkRecycled Encountered a non-recycled request and recycled it forcedly.
 org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter$RecycleRequiredException
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.checkRecycled(CoyoteAdapter.java:501)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.recycle(Http11Processor.java:1707)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.release(AbstractProtocol.java:1050)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:1018)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

---

```
02-Jul-2018 11:28:01.566 GRAVE [http-nio-80-exec-15] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process Error leyendo requerimiento, ignorado
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Calling [asyncOperation()] is not valid for a request with Async state [READ_WRITE_OP]
        at org.apache.coyote.AsyncStateMachine.asyncOperation(AsyncStateMachine.java:254)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.dispatchNonBlockingRead(AbstractProcessor.java:505)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.dispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:200)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
```

2. This trace below appears when the server has no handlers available (max open files reached):

   19-Jul-2018 13:21:40.990 GRAVE [http-nio-80-ClientPoller-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$PollerEvent.run Failed to register socket with selector from poller
    java.lang.NullPointerException
           at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.isEventsHighKilled(EPollArrayWrapper.java:174)
           at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.setUpdateEvents(EPollArrayWrapper.java:190)
           at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.add(EPollArrayWrapper.java:239)
           at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.implRegister(EPollSelectorImpl.java:178)
           at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.register(SelectorImpl.java:132)
           at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractSelectableChannel.register(AbstractSelectableChannel.java:212)
           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$PollerEvent.run(NioEndpoint.java:567)
           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller.events(NioEndpoint.java:682)
           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller.run(NioEndpoint.java:813)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
3. And this one appears when we stop an unresponsive tomcat:

   29-Jun-2018 10:31:12.143 GRAVE [http-nio-80-exec-727] org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch Exception while processing an asynchronous request
    java.lang.NullPointerException
           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:220)
           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.dispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:225)
           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:49)
           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Furthermore, lsof shows thousands of connections in this state:

```
java    5617 root 5884u  sock                0,7        0t0 185496425 can't identify protocol
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Any `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException` on the logs? Requests should not wait forever to get assigned a thread. May be is wrong timeout setting. How do you set queue size?

Comment: No TimeoutException. We have a ConnectionTimeout of 5s and a KeepAliveTimeout of 20s. We are trying now to set a MaxKeepAliveRequests=1 to avoid keep alive. The queue size is set internally in our application.

Comment: How this issue is seen on client side? That could give you additional info.

Comment: Tomcat was restarted without checking the client side, so impossible to know now if there were connections stucked on the client. We will have to wait the issue to happen again. Anyways thanks for your comments.